# Bulk collect into global temporary table

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am working in Oracle 11g and 12c environments.  I need to create a SP that does the following:

1. Reads data from two tables (join)
2. Fetch BULK COLLECT into a table with LIMIT
3. Based on what is in a few of the columns, I may need to create a duplicate record with different results in those columns.  So, one row may end up being two rows with different dates and quantities
4. Although the two rows will be unique to each other it may now collide with another set of data that I may or may not have processed yet.  This would result in duplicate PK records in my target table so, before inserting into the target table I need to compress and sum the qty field (group by) of the entire data set

I started writing just using Cursor and BULK COLLECT into a nested table with LIMIT but, of course, I need the entire data set to do the group by so I think I need to dump the data into a global temporary table once I have done step 3 above.  However, I have added quite a few more steps to processing my data and Im now second guessing my thoughts on how this should be done.  Not sure how else I would do it though since I cannot dump directly into the GTT without losing track of which set of data I am processing...unless I add a sequencer column to the GTT or something...which I suppose I could.  Maybe I am overthinking this.  I am working with a few hundred thousand records...could go up to a million.  I am looking for the best performance as well.  Here are the potential new steps:

1. Cursor c1 Reads data from two tables (join) - because I need to limit # fetched
2. Fetch BULK COLLECT into nested table with LIMIT 1000
3. manipulate the 1000 rows of data based on what is in a few of the columns and insert them into a Collection.  if the results meet a certain criteria insert another set of the data into the collection with slightly different data. The collection can now be > 1000 rows but wont be more than 2000 rows
4. Insert the collection into a GTT.  I would think this would be a FORALL INSERT INTO gtt.
5. if there are more records to process repeat steps 2 thru 4 until  c1%notfound
6. FORALL Insert the gtt table into the target table using a GROUP BY to eliminate duplicate PK records...  I would think I need to do this in smaller chunks as well right?  do I use a rownum loop to read/insert..not sure what the best practice is for the GTT.

I apreciate the advise on the best, fastest way to do.

Comment: it would help if you would add more details.table descriptions, sample data and expected output and what have you tried already.its easier that way.

Comment: Agreed with brenners, there's too much hand waving and no concrete problem statement or example code to work with here, so it's impossible to recommend any particular course of action (except to state the general rule-of-thumb: if you can do it all in SQL, it's probably best to do it all in SQL - and avoid the complicated GTT and PL/SQL if possible).

Comment: unfortunately, I am not able to give sample data due to confidentiality.  I was being general because I am looking for general answers.  Not looking for anyone to write my code. I thought using SQL meant context switching and I want to avoid context switching so I am not sure why I would want to avoid pl/sql.  Why avoid GTT?  If not GTT then what else is there except put it all in a physical table.  I imagined GTT as data in memory and not on disk so it would be faster...is this not true? Again, looking for what others have done in this situation.  I felt I provided enough info for that.

Comment: Can someone tell me when its appropriate to use a GTT?